# Can I set-up a mock to return regardless of generic type?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, nsubstitute

Code I'm attempting to test with unit tests does the following:

```
void DoSomething()
{
   var myTypeImplementation = _lifetimeScope.Resolve<IMyInterface<MyType>>();
   var mySecondTypeImplementation = _lifetimeScope.Resolve<IMyInterface<MySecondType>>();

   myTypeImplementation.Bar();
   mySecondTypeImplementation.Bar();
}
```

### Question

How can I mock `_lifetimeScope` (`ILifetimeScope`) by handling the generic type implicitly?

### What I've Tried

I have the following and it works, but there are many more types than just the 2 I've used in my example, so there's a *lot* of copy/paste:

```
        var mockFirstType = Substitute.For<IMyInterface<MyType>>();
        _mockLifetimeScope.Resolve<IMyInterface<MyType>().Returns(mockFirstType);

        
        var mockSecondType = Substitute.For<IMyInterface<MySecondType>>();
        _mockLifetimeScope.Resolve<IMyInterface<MySecondType>().Returns(mockSecondType);
```

After this set-up, I still need to assert, so now I have an assertion per type:

```
        mockFirstType.Received().Bar();
        mockSecondType.Received().Bar();
```

Instead, the ideal would be to write this test as a `Theory` and pass a `Type` maybe? But some alternative approach where I don't handle types explicitly would be a lot neater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

```
[Fact]
public void TestMethod()
{
    var myFirstVerificationCallback = GetVerificationCallback<MyType>();
    var mySecondVerificationCallback = GetVerificationCallback<MySecondType>();
    var myThirdVerificationCallback = GetVerificationCallback<MyThirdType>();

    myFirstVerificationCallback();
    mySecondVerificationCallback();
    myThirdVerificationCallback();
}

private Action GetVerificationCallback<T>()
{
    var typeMock = Substitute.For<IMyInterface<T>>();
    
    _mockLifetimeScope
        .Resolve<IMyInterface<T>>()
        .Returns(typeMock);

    return () => typeMock
        .Received()
        .Bar();
}
```

Option 2 (maybe):

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(typeof(MyType))]
[InlineData(typeof(MySecondType))]
[InlineData(typeof(MyThirdType))]
public void TestMethod(Type typeParameterType)
{
    var serviceTypeToMock = typeof(IMyInterface<>).MakeGenericType(typeParameterType);
    var substitution = Substitute.For(new Type[] {serviceTypeToMock}, Array.Empty<object>());

    _mockLifetimeScope
        .Resolve(serviceTypeToMock)
        .Returns(substitution);

    (substitution.Received() as dynamic).Bar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate you taking the time to answer this, number 2 looks exactly like what I was after. I'll give it a go now.

Comment: Yep, spot on. Thanks again mate.

Comment: No problem friend.